# Initialize literal in parameter to a function call and modify it - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift coming from C++. In C++, you can pass rvalues into a function like this:

```cpp
void f(string&& s) { s[0] = 'a'; }
f("foo");
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Swift? This won't compile:

```swift
func f(_ s: inout String) { s[0] = "a" }
f("foo") //error: cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: literals are not mutable
```

I know I could declare the String first and then pass it in, but that's more typing than I'd like to do

Comment: Make a variable `var foo = "foo"` and then pass that into your function `f(&foo)`, but you'll find string manipulation in Swift is a LOT different then most languages and something like `func f(_ s: inout String) { s = "a" + s.dropFirst() }` would actually compile (but I'm sure there's a better way to do it)  - have a look at [Strings and Characters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/)

Comment: Why even attempt to modify a string literal? What does it accomplish? You have no access to the modified literal after the call to `f`.

Comment: @HangarRash Since the value doesn't matter after the function call, that gives you even more reason to be able to modify it. Say you wanted to pass in an Int, perform some operations on it, and then print the result. Unless you can modify it, you'd have to type an extra line to either create the Int before the function call or to copy it inside the function.

Comment: @WaddleDee72 OK, so your goal here is to basically try to fight the language so you can be lazy by avoiding one line of code. It's Swift. Do things the Swift way. There's no reason to use `inout` for what you are describing. Just do what's needed inside the function, even if that means adding one extra line of code.

Comment: @HangarRash It *was* “the Swift way”, but stopped being so 7 years ago; link in my answer.

Comment: Let's be a bit more gentle on OP. Yes, Swift has a particular way of doing things, just like C++. When you try to bring practices from 1 lang into another, it's non-idiomatic at best, or just doesn't work. ["We don't do that here"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/we-dont-do-that-here) is a correct response, but let's not be dicks about it. The immutability of function arguments is a nice (and *intentional*) feature of Swift which we appreciate, but we should recognize how surprising that might be to outsiders seeing it for the first time, esp those used to the lawless land of C and such.

Answer (score 1):

`inout` doesn't make sense for a literal because you'd have no way to access it after modification. `var` is what you're looking for, but [it was removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md). [A property wrapper cannot replace the old behavior, either](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0293-extend-property-wrappers-to-function-and-closure-parameters.md#implementation-detail-property-wrappers).

```swift
func ƒ(@Wrapped _ string: String) {
  // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'string' is immutable
  string.replaceSubrange(...string.startIndex, with: "a")

  // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: '$string' is immutable
  $string { $0.replaceSubrange(...string.startIndex, with: "a") }
}
```

```swift
/// An affordance for adding extensions to every type.
@propertyWrapper public struct Wrapped<Value> {
  public var wrappedValue: Value
  public var projectedValue: Self { self }

  public init(wrappedValue: Value) {
    self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
  }
}

public extension Wrapped {
  mutating func callAsFunction(
    transform: (inout Value) throws -> Void
  ) rethrows {
    try transform(&wrappedValue)
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on comments by the OP below the question, I don't think there is any desire to return a value from the function. The OP just wants to modify the parameter value inside the function. The OP is just trying to avoid creating a local `var` inside the function. That's it.